# Separate functions which depend on each other

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to clean up my code an separate into functions that only have one task.
In v1 `joinDailyCo(url);` was defined inside `fetchUrl()`. Now I tried to move it out with

```
const url = fetchUrl();
joinDailyCo(url);
```

However, as soon I do that, I get the error message:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'join' of
>   undefined

```
const Daily = ({ eventSlug, tableId }) => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const iframeRef = useRef();
  const dailyRef = useRef();
  const joinedRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Join call
    const joinDailyCo = async (url) => {
      if (joinedRef.current) {
        // This is needed due to it never returning if there wasn't a meeting joined first.
        await dailyRef.current.leave();
      }
      await dailyRef.current.join({ url });
    };

    // Retrieve dailySessionId and meetingToken.
    const fetchUrl = async () => {
      try {
        const {
          data: { dailySessionId, meetingToken },
        } = await api.get(
          `events/${eventSlug}/space/tables/${tableId}/daily-auth/`
        );
        const url = `${DAILY_URL}/${dailySessionId}?t=${meetingToken}`;
        return url;
        // joinDailyCo(url);
      } catch (error) {
        Sentry.captureException(error);
      }
    };

    const url = fetchUrl();
    url && joinDailyCo(url);
  }, [eventSlug, tableId]);

  useEffect(() => {
    dailyRef.current = DailyIframe.wrap(iframeRef.current, {
      // showLeaveButton: true,
    });
    dailyRef.current.on(eventTypes.LEFT_MEETING, () => {
      joinedRef.current = false;
    });
    dailyRef.current.on(eventTypes.JONING_MEETING, () => {
      joinedRef.current = true;
    });
    return () => {
      dailyRef.current.destroy();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <iframe
      ref={iframeRef}
      className={classes.root}
      title="Video Meeting"
      allow="camera; microphone; display-capture; fullscreen"
    />
  );
};

export default Daily;
```

Comment: What is value of joinedRef?

Comment: Hi Anh, it is either true or false. I added the full component for a better understanding.

Comment: I think when component mouting the dailyRef.current is not asign any value for it

Comment: You have to check if any of the ref.current is actually a defined value, like `ref && ref.current && ref.current.join()`